# Database diagram for multiple selection

Tags: database, database-design, uml

I am having a logic problem while designing my database for a online survey. Part of my software consist in a survey generator where the user can create a question and add checkboxes and radiobuttons as options. So every question have an ID, however 1 question can have many options.

So far I have only work with software where the user can choose from determined range of options so I can collect the input and store it in the respective column of a table. However this is a different case for me because the columns are not there yet. I am trying to figure out a way to work around however I have been block for hours.

Comment: What is this? An UML question or a DB design question. It can hardly be both.

Comment: 1. Show what you already have. If you did several tries, show all of them. Also be more specific on what you are asking. Finally this question has nothing to do with UML.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by options you mean Possible answers to a question

```
Question  -Tracks the question of the survey
QID PK

Answers - Tracks the available answers for a survey item
AID PK

QuestionAnswers  - Identifies which answers can be used on which questions
QUID  PK
AID   PK

Users  - identifies a person taking a survey
UID  PK

UserAnswers - Identifes the answers a user has selected for a survey and relates to both users and questionAnswers  thus limiting which answers can be used for a question but each row allows the user to select 1-M answers as needed.
UID  PK
QID  PK
AID  PK
```